# Jump to point in timeline from url

Tags: flash, web, adobe

I have a web site that is going to link to a new web page built in Flash.  The main site will have links pointing to that one flash page throughout.  Depending on where you are in the site I'd like to open that flash at different points in the timeline.  Is that something that can be done, and if so, how should I go about doing it?

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass a var to the  call of the webpage that will then pass it on to the .swf as a flashVar.  It will require a little js/jquery to create the page correctly and that dynamically loads the .swf.

In the swf, you'll have to have a function that takes the flashVar, i.e. 'frameNum=40' and it will call gotoAndStop(frameNum);

What parts do you want specific help with?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you should have access to Flash source file. 
Check out this article on Adobe's devnet: http://www.adobe.com/jp/devnet/flash/articles/deep_linking.html

General approach is the same as Gone3d said:

1. You add a callback-method in flash-source.
2. You access a swf
   object with javascript and call its callback-method.

also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109077/trigger-a-actionscript-function-in-a-flash-object-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SWFObject allows me to do what I need.  I found this [tutorial](http://www.flashkit.com/tutorials/Actionscripting/Passing_-Nuno_Mir-1815/index.php).